# How to create a new block in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am trying to create a blockchain and have created a genesis block successfully. I now want to create 2 more blocks on the genesis block using Hyperledger Fabric in Linux. So any help here would be appreciated.
And also do we have to create a new channel for creating new block or will the existing channel work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install and instantiate a chaincode. Then you can do a (write) invoke against that chaincode, which will create new blocks. This will all occur on the existing channel.

Comment: @S.M. please take a look here for more details and examples: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples

Comment: @ArtemBarger yes, it helped. Thankyou for it